# Optimise PHP array extraction query (using functional operators if possible)

Tags: php

I was trying to figure out if there was a better method to transpose this (Laravel Collection) into a regular PHP array (preferably using functional operators).

### Current Data

```
array:4 [▼
  "HIGH" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:15 [▶]
    1 => array:15 [▶]
  ]
  "MEDIUM" => array:3 [▶]
  "LOW" => array:2 [▶]
  "INFO" => array:1 [▶]
]
```

### Current Code

```
 $labelarr = [];
 $countarr = [];

 foreach ($labelCount as $k => $v) {
    array_push($labelarr, $k);
    $currentcount = count($v);
    array_push($countarr, $currentcount);
 }
```

So I have two arrays; one containing the labels, i. e. ['HIGH, 'MEDIUM', 'LOW, ...], and one containing the count [2, 3, 2, ...].

Is there a better way to optimise the above (trying to learn new methods)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of functions to achieve this.  [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) extracts the keys of the array, so gives your labels. [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) allows you to apply a function to each element of an array and this allows you to do the `count()`.

```
$labelCount = ["HIGH" => [1,2], "MEDIUM" => [2,4,6]];

$labelarr = array_keys($labelCount);
$countarr = array_values(array_map(function ($data) { return count($data); }, $labelCount));

print_r($labelarr);
print_r($countarr);
```

will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => HIGH
    [1] => MEDIUM
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
)
```

Although I'm not sure if this optimises it as sometimes using a simple `foreach()` can actually be quicker and more readable.